# Simplify a php repeat script

Tags: php, arrays, simplify

I was wondering if there a way to simplify this code ?
I tried many things, but not simple...

Thanks!

```
$pos = strpos_arr(cPR("description"), $arraylist_3);
    if ($pos === false) {
    } else {
       $error = true;
       $error_text.= $error_3;
    }

$pos = strpos_arr(cPR("description"), $arraylist_4);
if ($pos === false) {
} else {
   $error = true;
   $error_text.= $error_4;
}

$pos = strpos_arr(cP("description"), $arraylist_5);
if ($pos === false) {
} else {
   $error = true;
   $error_text.= $error_5;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do a foreach loop?

```
$arrays = [
    $arraylist_3 => $error_3,
    $arraylist_4 => $error_4,
    $arraylist_5 => $error_5
];

foreach ( $arrays as $arr => $error_msg )
{
    $pos = strpos_arr(cPR("description"), $arr);
    if ($pos !== false) {
       $error = true;
       $error_text .= $error_msg;
    }
}
```